# prevent parent class 'forgetting' local vars set by children: php

Tags: php, oop

I have this class

```
class Validator implements iValidation{
    protected
        $_fields,
        $_errors;
    public function __construct($fields){
        $this->_errors = array();
        $this->_fields = $fields;
    }
    public function validate(){
        $map = unserialize( iValidation::map );
        foreach ($this->_fields as $field_type => $data){
            if ( array_key_exists( $field_type, $map ) ){
                $class = "Validate_{$map["$field_type"]}" ;
                $object = new $class($data);
                $object->validate();
                unset($object);
            }            
        }
    }
    public function getErrors(){
        return $this->_errors;
    }
}
```

Now this class loops through an array given in the format

```
$admin_test_data = array(
    "firstname" => "Alex1",
    "surname" => "Morley-Finch",
    "username" => "alex123",
    "password" => "cheese",
    "re_password" => "cheese",
    "email_address" => "alex54353hotmail.co.uk",
    "user_type" => "ADMIN",
    "add_admin" => "Add Admin",
);
```

I have a map that describes the type of validation on each field that is declared like so:

```
define(
    "VALIDATION_MAP",
    serialize(
            array(
                // FIELD => VALIDATION TYPE
                "firstname" => "Name",
                "surname" => "Name",
                "agency_name" => "Agency_Name",
                "agency_office" => "Name",
                "username" => "Username",
                "email_address" => "Email_Address",
                "password" => "Password",
            )
    )
);

interface iValidation{
    public function __construct($data);
    public function validate();
    const map = VALIDATION_MAP;
}
```

And I have sub classes One of which is like this:

```
class Validate_Name extends Validator implements iValidation{
    private $_data;
    public function __construct($data){
        $this->_data = $data;
    }
    public function validate(){
        $data = $this->_data;
        $length = strlen($data);
        if ( $length > 40 ){
            $this->_errors[] = "Cannot be more than 40 characters";
        }
        if ( $length < 3 ){
            $this->_errors[] = "Cannot be less than 3 characters";
        }
        if ( !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/", $data) ){
            $this->_errors[] = "A-Z characters only";
        }
    }
}
```

And the whole framework is used like so:

```
$validator = new Validator($admin_test_data);
$validator->validate(); //  ^ defined earlier ^^^
$errors = $validator->getErrors();
```

Now after all that background info... lets get to the problem.

I'm probably doing some EXTREMELY stupid but I can't figure it out and Google isn't doing a good job of enlightening me ( or I'm not doing a good job of asking google )

The sub classes reference `$this->_errors[] = "This is the error";` and when using `die( var_dump( $this->_errors ) );` inside the sub class, the errors for that class appear as they should.

However if I call `die( var_dump( $validator->getErrors() ) );` outside the classes, the array is empty.

Asif the parent has forgotten all the values the children set?

Whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each field you validate in `Validator`, you create an instance of the required implementation of `iValidation`.

Now the child validator validates, and it finds errors. It adds those errors to its `_errors` instance attribute.

When it's done validating, the child instance is discarded. And that's where the problem lies, since the errors found were assigned *to the **child instance's** `_errors` attribute, not that of the **parent instance***.

Nothing ever gets assigned to `Validator::_errors`, because those properties are in different objects.